# Cannot open/find standalone iModel when running display-test-app

Tags: imodeljs

I am a beginner who want to use the imodeljs to display building model. I was trying to use the display-test-app but failed to see the model through Electron. I followed all Build Instruction and got the error message when run `npm run start` in `display-test-app` folder.

The error message say it cannot open standalone iModel, and either I cannot find any `iModel` in my folder. Thanks for any suggestion.

> WARNING: Frontend requested "electron://frontend/appicon.ico", but C:\users\peng-yu.chen\desktop\imodeljs\test-apps\display-test-app\lib\webresources\appicon.ico does not exist
>   WARNING: Frontend requested "electron://frontend/locales/en-PSEUDO/iModelJs.json", but C:\users\peng-yu.chen\desktop\imodeljs\test-apps\display-test-app\lib\webresources\locales\en-PSEUDO\iModelJs.json does not exist
>   WARNING: Frontend requested "electron://frontend/locales/en-PSEUDO/CoreTools.json", but C:\users\peng-yu.chen\desktop\imodeljs\test-apps\display-test-app\lib\webresources\locales\en-PSEUDO\CoreTools.json does not exist
>   WARNING: Frontend requested "electron://frontend/locales/en-PSEUDO/SVTTools.json", but C:\users\peng-yu.chen\desktop\imodeljs\test-apps\display-test-app\lib\webresources\locales\en-PSEUDO\SVTTools.json does not exist
>   WARNING: Frontend requested "electron://frontend/locales/en/SVTTools.json", but C:\users\peng-yu.chen\desktop\imodeljs\test-apps\display-test-app\lib\webresources\locales\en\SVTTools.json does not exist

[image]

Answer (score 1):

display-test-app is a developer testing/debugging tool. It requires you to have an iModel (a file with file extension .bim or .ibim) on your machine so it can open and view it.

[simple-viewer-app](https://github.com/imodeljs/simple-viewer-app) is the recommended sample viewing application. It can open iModels from iModelHub. It's a good starting point to build your own application upon.